# How can I make the content of a UIWebView load with an animation?

Tags: iphone, html, animation, uiwebview, load

I have a UIWebView that I am loading with a string full of HTML. There are times when I am paging through the content quickly, and when the app catches up, the UIWebView loads the HTML and it just pops up there.

I want to somehow make it a little more visually appealing. Is there a way to subtly fade into the content of the webView? Make it a little less shocking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the webview's `.alpha` value to `0`, and animate it to `1` when the webpage is done loading.

To determine if the webpage is loaded and rendered, either use the webview delegate methods, or add a piece of javascript to the page (if possible) to explicitly call back when the page load is finished. You can simply do `<script language=javascript>window.location="done:";</script>` and catch the load of this `done:` url in you webview delegate method (`-webview:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`)